# Why don't I see linear chirp for IFFT of gaussian with quadratic phase?

Tags: fourier-transform, python, pulse

I am trying to set up a program for numerically simulating a pulse in the time domain after it is transmitted through a material that imparts linear, quadratic, and third order phase in the spectral domain. Basically the program makes a properly formatted complex spectrum (for use with np.fft.ifft)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.fft import ifft

def gauss_omega_forIFFT(lam0,tfwhm,L,ng,GVD,Nsamp=4e6,TOD=0,R=2000):
    #enter lam0 in nm, tfwhm in fs, GVD in fs^2/mm, ng=group index, L in mm, TOD in fs**2/mm
    w0 = 800/lam0*2*np.pi*(0.375) #in PHz*rad
    ffwhm = 0.44/tfwhm #PHz
    wsig = 2*np.pi*ffwhm/(2*np.sqrt(2*np.log(2))) #rad*PHz
    
    c = 2.998*10**(-4) #mm/fs
    PD = L/c #phase delay, in fs
    phi1 = PD*ng
    phi2 = GVD*L
    phi3 = TOD*L
    
    Nsamp = int(Nsamp)
    Nposneg = Nsamp//2
    w1 = np.linspace(0,R*w0,Nposneg)
    w2 = np.linspace(-R*w0,0,Nsamp-Nposneg)
    wsamp = np.concatenate([w1,w2])

    p1_pos = phi1*(wsamp-w0)
    p2_pos = phi2/2*(wsamp-w0)**2
    p3_pos = phi3/6*(wsamp-w0)**3
    p_pos = p1_pos+p2_pos+p3_pos
    
    p1_neg = phi1*(wsamp+w0)
    p2_neg = phi2/2*(wsamp+w0)**2
    p3_neg = phi3/6*(wsamp+w0)**3
    p_neg = p1_neg+p2_neg+p3_neg

    spec = np.exp(-(wsamp-w0)**2/(2*wsig**2))*np.exp(-1j*(p_pos)) + np.exp(-(wsamp+w0)**2/(2*wsig**2))*np.exp(-1j*(p_neg))

    return wsamp,spec,p_pos,p_neg

#input parameters and get complex spectrum 
f0 = 0.375 #PHz
ffwhm = 0.15
tfwhm = 0.44/ffwhm
lam0 = 800*0.375/f0
L = 1 #mm
GVD = 10
ng = 0

wsamp,spec,ppos,pneg = gauss_omega_forIFFT(lam0,tfwhm,L,ng,GVD)

#ifft complex spectrum for t domain signal
sig_t = np.fft.ifftshift(ifft(spec))

#get real part of signal and time axis
sig_t_cos = sig_t + np.conjugate(sig_t)
sig_t_cos /= sig_t_cos.max()
T = 1/(np.diff(wsamp)[0]/(2*np.pi))
t = np.linspace(-T/2,T/2,Nsamp)

#plot
plt.plot(t,sig_t_cos)
plt.xlabel('time (fs)')
plt.xlim(-30,30)
plt.title('time domain signal')

plt.show()
```

I get the following time domain signal. Instead of being a Gaussian-like envelope pulse with a linear chirp all the quadratic phase seems to do is add these weird modulations (it does broaden the pulse like it should). The spectral amplitude and phases returned by gauss_omega_forIFFT() look correct at positive and negative frequencies. The default frequency range is set to make the sampling period in time domain as 1/1000 the wave period. The default number of samples is set to make the time domain range 1000 cycles of the wave period. From what I can tell there is no issue with the sampling in terms of numerical errors (if I extend the frequency range and increase Nsamp it doesn't change anything).

[image]

I am a bit stumped at this point. Esepcially, since if I ifft the spectrum with no GVD (no quadratic spectral phase) I get the correct waveform (so I know I am implementing the numpy ifft correctly). Here is the ifft with GVD = 0. Likewise, if I make make the linear spectral phase non-zero it delays the pulse accordingly. Perhaps I just do not fully understand how the quadratic spectral phase translates into linear chirp?

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I resolved this to be sign errors in the phase terms for the negative frequency terms in the spectral phase. Firstly the nth order terms should be changed to:
p1_neg = -phi1*(wsamp+w0),
p2_neg = phi2/2*(wsamp+w0)**2,
p3_neg = -phi3/6*(wsamp+w0)**3,
p_neg = p1+neg+p2_neg+p3_neg

and the overall phase term for the negative spectral content is: 
exp(1j*p_neg)

Basically the negative frequency needs to have the opposite sign "phi2" otherwise you get standing waves which caused the modulations I saw.

Comment: Welcome here, gmac! Your comment seems to actually be an answer to your question. I'd ask you to actually copy & paste the comment into the answer field, so people see this question was answered :) Answering one's own questions is explicitly encouraged around here, too!